# What could be the Customs duty at Chennai (MAA) airport for Panasonic 55 inch used (>3 years) TV

Tags: luggage, local-customs, chennai

I bought a TV (Panasonic 55 inch NON-Smart TV) like 3 years back and using it. The airline says, extra baggage will be $200 which I can do, but I'm not sure how much will be the custom duty at Chennai airport (or India in general). If anyone took similar TV before to India/Chennai, let me know please. I have the receipt of the TV purchase with me.

Comment: Customs duty is based on the value of the item, it doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: @Aganju That is wrong. When importing an item, you have to pay customs duty and in most countries a value added tax. The customs duty usually depends on what kind of product it is and sometimes where the product was manufactured, bought and/or imported from. The value added tax is for regular products usually fixed, but does in some countries also depend on what kind of product it is. Most European countries e.g. have a reduced VAT for food and specific services.

Comment: Will the custom duty be charged on the value of the product from the Origin country or importing country? Also, this question is specific to TV ONLY. If my TV price is $200 and used for 3 years, what could be the duty?